# Player Ai for games involving scoring goals like soccer, hockey, basketball?

Tags: ai

I've been working on a soccer game, and was thinking of different ways to program player AI's and was wondering how they actually work. The concept is probably similar to all games where there are balls and goals like Soccer, Hockey, Basketball etc.

Which algorithm do they use ? I imagine if you have the ball, you can use A*, to figure out a path passed other "enemy" players and score. That seems simple to implement.

But if you do not have the ball then then it becomes really complicated - you could either play "zone" in which case, you stay within a particular region on of the playing area, and orient yourself towards the ball. Or switch to playing "man", in which case you stick to some player on the other team.

Was wondering what other algorithms people use, as machine learning for a simple mobile game seems like over kill.

Comment: frankly your best bet is to talk to coaches and see what strategies they teach to their team.

Comment: @ratchetfreak actually the machine learning forums has some great ideas. Talking to coaches isn't as good because you can get most of their ideas just watching games, and its a lot quicker.

Comment: Talking to coaches is probably only relevant if you already have a functional AI and you want to tweak it by adding some personality and recognisable plays.

Comment: @KaizerSozay are you still looking for an answer to this question or did you already find what you are looking for? I'm happy to answer but don't want to spend 30 minutes and bump the question if you already have an answer :)

Comment: @P.Hopkinson I and many others would be delighted to hear your answer! I do have a strategy which I will put up in a post at a later date, but it could be "mediocre" compared to what you have... .put your answer up, then we can compare and comment!